# ContentDistribution endpoint - exclude links that refer to 'This content delivery has expired'

Tags: contentdistribution

When calling the ['ContentDistribution'](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm) endpoint,

1. What are some possible reasons for receiving files with the key `ExpiryDate = Null`
2. Is there a way to filter the results from `DistributionPublicUrl` to exclude links that refer to 'This content delivery has expired'?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `WHERE ExpiryDate < TODAY` ??

Comment: What do you mean?
This is how it looks:
[Screen Shot](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/5JpF0zorm3nb.png).

Comment: `WHERE ExpiryDate != NULL AND ExpiryDate >= TODAY` to filter for valid items